# How do I find an attribute within nested tags in Jquery?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have to find a data-target through Jquery which is enclosed under lot of HTML tags. So how do I find a certain attribute through the tags?
i.e. The tags #Timer1 and #Timer2 values which are receiving through HTML are not getting outputted under JQuery's var Timer1 & var Timer2.

```
<table class="table">
<?php
    $table = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM Timers');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ 
      ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">

            <tr>
            <th>Timer 1</th>
            <th data-target="Timer1"><?php echo $row['Timer1']; ?></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th>Timer 2</th>
            <th data-target="Timer2"><?php echo $row['Timer2']; ?></th>
            </tr>

              <th> 
            <a href="#" data-role="update" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Update</a> 
             </th> 
        </tr>

     <?php
          } 
     ?>
    </table>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=update]', function() {
    id = $(this).data('id');

    var Timer1=  $('#'+id).find('#Timer1').closest('tr');
    var Timer2 = $(this).closest('tr[id=' + id + ']').find("th[data-target='Timer2']").text();
    //putting value in input box
    $("#ids").val(id)
    $('#Timer1').val(Timer1);
    $('#Timer2').val(Timer2);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  });

...
...
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to find. What is your expected output and what is going wrong?

Comment: So in JQuery; var Timer1 should output the value that is receiving in php under the tag "data-target="Timer1" . I am not able to receive it since I am using nested tags.

Comment: Shouldn't `.find('#Timer1')` be `.find("th[data-target='Timer1']")`

Comment: @Nick I have tried both but it works only if I remove one <tr> before ```<th>Timer 1</th>```

Comment: It looks like you have incorrect HTML - you have `<tr id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">` followed immediately by `<tr>`

Comment: I was under the impression that we can use nested <tr> tags one under another. If not, what is the solution?

Comment: No - not unless you put the nested `<tr>` elements inside a new table. Alternatively you could perhaps replace `<tr id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">` with `<tbody id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">`

Comment: @Nick Perfect!! Thank you so much. Been cracking my head for hours for this. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Which worked - the nested table or the tbody?

Comment: I tried the <tbody> and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have invalid HTML markup with nested `<tr>` elements:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
```

is followed immediately by another `<tr>`. Since you don't already have a `<tbody>` element, you can work around this by changing the `tr` in the first element to `tbody`. You will then need to change the closing tag to `</tbody>` too.